# Domains hosted on Ubuntu Server(Plesk) can only send outgoing mails

Tags: plesk, ubuntu, mx

I have a dedicated server(Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) with Plesk installed. I have few domains hosted on the server.

I am only able to send outgoing mails(from webmail), none of the domains are able to receive mails.

I checked mxtoolbox, it says "no records exist" for all the domains hosted on the server.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing (I'm pretty new to servers)

Comment: Do domains have MX records set up?  Are they pointing to your domain or  IP address?

Comment: How do I set up MX records (like mx01.domainname.com, mx02). I mean, i can add them in DNS Zone of the domain in cloudflare. but where do I define them.

Comment: Sorry,I don't know plesk. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

***If you are using Postfix***, make sure that you are not trying to send from a send-only SMTP server:

[How to Install and Configure Postfix as a Send-Only SMTP Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Navigate to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Scroll down to make sure that the following parameters are set to the values below (substituting your own values where appropriate):

```
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, custom-website.com, localhost.com, , localhost
```

Restart Postfix:

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```

---

***If you are integrating your email with a commercial client such as Outlook or Gmail***, make sure that your are testing for incoming mail from another commercial email address.

For example, do not test for incoming email from `user@custom-website.com`.

Instead, send from a tried-and-true email service like `user@gmail.com` or `user@outlook.com`.

If the mail reaches your server, then you probably have a problem with outgoing email from `custom-website.com`, rather than incoming mail.

---

***If all else fails***, make sure that the incoming email did not end up in spam.

Also, make sure that your MX records are set up properly. Most hosting providers have guides to help you set these specifications up properly. Here are some general instructions:

[General Instructions to change the MX records](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/configure-email-delivery.html#alink2)